# How to replace value in DataTable specified by Index?

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to find out how to efficiently replace requested value in DataTable.
For example I got some random DataTable and I want to replace row[5] column[2] value with some string while I don't know whats the initial value.

Anyone got solution for it?

Comment: `DataTableName.Rows[5][2] = value` => is this what you want? Provide [mcve] to help figuring out your issue.

Comment: _"replace .. with some string while I don't know whats the initial value."_ what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just directly access the cell by;

```
dt.Rows[5][2] = "some string"
```

Of course you should check if the index is not out of range.

Comment: Of course it works. I was looking too deep while the answer was that simple :)